# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

why this error comes?

I am using windows authentication. But i am getting error

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

can any one help me in this how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a programming question... how?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it means you're trying to connect from an impersonated context and you did not set up constrained delegation. See [Manage Kerberos Authentication Issues in a Reporting Services Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679930%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for details and troubleshooting.

Comment: @Remus.. Is it possible can you give me some solution steps here to resolve kerberos issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I always prefer to use the 'impersonation' settings in the ISS configuration that do not set the user/password in the web.config. Everything was fine in the QA environment, but then I passed to the production environment and some options of the web site in production started to show the 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error.

The issue was that I copied the web-site configuration from the QA server, using the 'Save configuration to a file' option in IIS6 while creating a brand new Application Pool in the production server.

After several hours trying to solve this error, I just deleted the Application Pool, and used the 'Save configuration to a file' option to copy the Application Pool configuration and then restored it to the new server.

If you copy the web-site configuration, also copy the Application Pool configuration. That solved my problem, without changing anything about the authentication method, the database or the web-site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Setup:
I had a report accessing datasource A, with a subreport which accessed datasource B.
The report connections were set to use Integrated Security.

From my development machine:
The "main" report would run perfectly fine from my development environment *(as it was running everything as me.)*

From the server:
I was able to execute the subreport directly, with no problem.
The main report would run, with the text **"Error: Subreport could not be shown."**

Actual Problem:
**The subreport was executing under the NTAUTH\ANON user**, because it was the Reporting Services code which was calling the sub-report. This error was in the SSRS Logs:
*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.*

Solution:
Set up the sub-report data connection to execute using a SQL User login.
Only grant that user execute on the particular procedure you're calling for the report.
This allowed me to get the report working without involving other departments that controlled the application servers (modifying web.configs or IIS configurations)