# Localhost Vs Server name error in asp.net IIS server?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have webapplication which working on AD (database access too). The site is working fine when I use http:// locahost:8081/clients.aspx, but if I use htt://servername.domain.com/clients.aspx is throwing exception for **"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'"**  at

```
Client = (From c In SAEntitties.Dim_Client
          Where C.Users.Any(Function(user) user.UserName = username)
          Select c).ToList()
```

How to handle this?

### Update

I disabled window authentication in IIS for Website. Enabled `Basic` authentication. It is working fine.

Why Windows Authentication doesn't work?

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718867/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon

Comment: what is your iis version

Comment: @Josh It is working with localhost with AD access. Only if I use servername then only problem.

Comment: What browser are you using? Is it configured to send domain credentials to servers other than localhost?

Comment: in firefox and IE. in firfox it is asking AD credentials then giving this error. this is on IIS7

Answer (score 0):

I have not experience yet integration with AD, but just in case, I think that is a good shot.

If you are using IIS 7.0 with Application Pools, you should try to change the original configuration of the pool you are using to NetworkService.

To do so, choose Application Pools -> "YourPool" -> Advanced configurations
Under Process Model, click Identity, and select NetworkServices within the dropdown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Elek, localhost in IE working fine (not with server name). In firefox localhost and servername both not working.